# Go install doesn't create bin file

Tags: go

Issue is similar to the one described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26694271/go-install-doesnt-create-any-bin-file) but the answer did not help me.

I use Go 1.4 built from source.
I have issued `$ go install -x -a` to force the rebuild of all packages (although I only made a change to a single go file). The project is well structured and contains a command in a file named main.go with `package main` and `func main()`
I am running out of ideas but gained a better understanding of the build process...

```
$ go env
GOARCH="386"
GOBIN=""
GOCHAR="8"
GOEXE=""
GOHOSTARCH="386"
GOHOSTOS="linux"
GOOS="linux"
GOPATH="/home/jdevoo/Downloads/go"
GORACE=""
GOROOT="/home/jdevoo/go"
GOTOOLDIR="/home/jdevoo/go/pkg/tool/linux_386"
CC="gcc"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m32 -pthread -fmessage-length=0"
CXX="g++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What about go build then go install (no parameter)? Would you see your program compiled in `/home/jdevoo/Downloads/go/bin`? Where is your main.go? Directly under `/home/jdevoo/Downloads/go/src`?

Comment: tried - no change. The file main.go is under `github.com/eris-ltd/decerver/cmd/decerver` - I see install generating the archives but not run the last linker step

Comment: Where is your `main.go`? Directly under `/home/jdevoo/Downloads/go/src`?

Comment: my $GOPATH does not include multiple entries and I tried with a simple hello program which worked well and produced hello binary

Comment: Can you try and move your main.go under a subfolder within `/home/jdevoo/Downloads/go/src`? Or did you mean that your `GOPATH` hasn't even a `src` in it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really depends on where exactly is your `main.go`.

It should be in `$GOPATH/src/yourProject/main.go`, for a `go install` to generate a `$GOPATH/bin/yourProject`.
That is what "[Your first program](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#Command)" describes.

`$GOPATH` is [your workspace](https://golang.org/doc/code.html#Workspaces), and should always include `src`, `pkg` and `bin`.

To get a binary specifically for that command:

```
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/eris-ltd/decerver/cmd/decerver/
go get
# or
go install
```

Note the `-x` option is supposed to "print the command" only.
`-a` would force rebuilding.

Comment: roger that. Workspace contains the 3 folders. The application was installed using `go get github.com/eris-ltd/decerver` followed by `cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/eris-ltd/decerver/cmd/decerver/` then `go get -d .` and `go install` - this worked and had produced the original binary. All I tried to do is modify one file and re-generate the executable. That's why I am stuck - not sure what is wrong... super weird

Comment: what else can prevent the linker from kicking in? Go is leaving me with the archive files... that's it

Comment: Maybe that modified go file isn't used by main.go, and the build process doesn't rebuild the `decerver` command as a result?

Comment: OK - I managed to get a new binary by accident. I issued `go get -x` from the directory containing main.go